# Why can't i select objects using the outliner tab?

Tags: select

Pressing "select objects" from the drop-down menu after right clicking on it doesn't select the objects in the 3d viewport. I'm confused because this was working yesterday and now it doesn't.

[image]

Can someone shed some light on this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are viewing the Outliner in Scenes mode

[image]

You need to change it to View Layer mode

[image]

Seems like it should work in both modes, but it doesn't.